# write a variable that takes a list of functions

Tags: arrays, c, function-pointers, declaration

I want to write a variable that takes a list of functions, is that even possible? to have a list of functions in C?

example:

```c
// this type is for one function
void (*f)(void) = func1;

// but this is what I need
/*TYPE*/ vf = { func1, func2, NULL };
```

I **dont** want to build new struct that hold the function and the next function, I want to like i mentioned above, is that possible without creating a dedicated struct?

note: I am not bound to a specific C standard

Comment: Create an array?

Comment: If you mean an array, you surely can have an array of function pointers.

Comment: C doesn't have a primitive "list" type, but you can create whatever data structures you desire.  Build a list and populate it with functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This record

```
void (*f)(void) = func1;
```

declares one pointer to function.

This record

```
void ( * vf[] )( void ) = { func1, func2, NULL };
```

or

```
void ( * vf[3] )( void ) = { func1, func2, NULL };
```

declares an array of pointers to functions.

You could simplify the declaration using a typedef either for the function type or for a pointer to the function type as for example

```
typedef void Func( void );
Func * vf[3] = { func1, func2, NULL };
```

or

```
typedef void ( *FuncPtr )( void );
FuncPtr vf[3] = { func1, func2, NULL };
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start with a type-alias, like for example this:

```
typedef void (function_type)(void);
```

Then you can use this to declare variables like any other type:

```
function_type *f = &func1;
```

And as an almost normal standard type, this can of course be used to define arrays:

```
function_type *vf[] = { &func1, &func2, NULL };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is auxiliary answer to other ones.

If our compiler supports `typeof` extension (a feature in upcoming C23) then you can do:

```
typeof(void(void))* vf[] = { func1, func2, NULL };
```